# ¿Cómo puedo volver a ejecutar o finalizar el programa en Python?

Tags: python

Este fragmento pequeño simula el tiro de dos dados, la finalidad del programa es mostrar el número que aleatoriamente toca a cada dado y después sumarlos. Mí problema es que quiero que el programa al final me pregunte si quiero volver a tirar los dados o finalizar el programa.
Si alguien puede orientarme en la manera mas optima seria de mucha ayuda.

```
def TirarDados():

    dado = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    suma = 0
    for tiro in range(2):
        
        result = dado[random.randint(0, 5)]
        print('Dado', tiro + 1, ':', result)
        
        suma += result

    print('Sumados son:', suma)


TirarDados()
```

Comment: ¿Conoces el `while`?

Comment: si lo conozco pero no supe como aplicarlo correctamente.

Comment: `while True: if input("continuar, si o no?").lower() == "no":  break`

Answer (score 1):

Cuando quieres repetir algo dependiendo de una entrada del usuario:

```
TirarDados()
while True:
    opcion = input("¿Quieres seguir (S/n)")
    if opcion == "n":
        break
    # Si no, aqui seguimos con otra iteración"
    TirarDados()
```

Ejecuto una tirada de dados al comenzar, y luego pregunto. Si la respusta es "n", hago un `break` para escapar del `while` y terminar el programa.

Ese es el patrón usual. Sólo necesitas reemplazar `TirarDados()` por aquello que quieras ejecutar.

#### Demo

```
import random

def TirarDados():
    dado = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    suma = 0
    for tiro in range(2):
        result = dado[random.randint(0, 5)]
        print('Dado', tiro + 1, ':', result)

        suma += result

    print('Sumados son:', suma)


TirarDados()
while True:
    opcion = input("¿Quieres seguir (S/n)")
    if opcion == "n":
        break
    # Si no, aqui seguimos con otra iteración"
    TirarDados()
```

produce

```
Dado 1 : 6
Dado 2 : 1
Sumados son: 7
¿Quieres seguir (S/n)S
Dado 1 : 2
Dado 2 : 4
Sumados son: 6
¿Quieres seguir (S/n)S
Dado 1 : 1
Dado 2 : 4
Sumados son: 5
¿Quieres seguir (S/n)n

Process finished with exit code 0
```